Websocket reconnect on server side
im quite a good javascript developer.i currently finalizing a project i and am now building redundancy into websocket connections..so far so good however I'm kind off stuck at this scenario.
Suppose the server or vps that hosts the websocket connection experiences a blink in terms of of access to the internet.will node continue listening on which ever port when the internet connection is reestablished. I'm unable to recreate this scenario cause the vps only allows suspend and reboot but no blink.i was thinking about using pm2 but am.not sure if pm2 can or will resume the websocket .
I was thinking about adding an event listener within the wss code.
Has anyone had any success with this issue.thanks
